# Unable to return String type for a function

Tags: rust

I am trying to solve a practice problem where an input list is given containing words. I have to embed them in a sentence one by one.

The program is almost complete except that I am unable to figure out how to return a String type. Actually I have to form a vector so as to return multiple statements. Now after I have pushed sentences into Vector, the problem is how can I return vector elements (as much no of list elements).

```rust
pub fn build_proverb(list: &[&str]) -> String {
    let empty = String::new();
    let mut vecList: Vec<String> = Vec::new();

    // match list.len() {

    // }

    if list.len() < 1 {
        empty
    } else {
        for i in 0..(list.len()) {
            if (i + 1) < list.len() {
                vecList.push(format!(
                    "For want of a {} the {} was lost.\n",
                    list[i],
                    list[i + 1]
                ));
            }
            if i == list.len() - 1 {
                vecList.push(format!("And all for the want of a {}.\n", list[0]));
            }
        }

        vecList // This is where i am getting return type error
    }
}
```

Also some test cases against which I have to test it:

```rust
use proverb::build_proverb;

#[test]
fn test_two_pieces() {
    let input = vec!["nail", "shoe"];
    let expected = vec![
        "For want of a nail the shoe was lost.",
        "And all for the want of a nail.",
    ]
    .join("\n");
    assert_eq!(build_proverb(&input), expected);
}

// Notice the change in the last line at three pieces.
#[test]
#[ignore]
fn test_three_pieces() {
    let input = vec!["nail", "shoe", "horse"];
    let expected = vec![
        "For want of a nail the shoe was lost.",
        "For want of a shoe the horse was lost.",
        "And all for the want of a nail.",
    ]
    .join("\n");
    assert_eq!(build_proverb(&input), expected);
}

#[test]
#[ignore]
fn test_one_piece() {
    let input = vec!["nail"];
    let expected = String::from("And all for the want of a nail.");
    assert_eq!(build_proverb(&input), expected);
}

#[test]
#[ignore]
fn test_zero_pieces() {
    let input: Vec<&str> = vec![];
    let expected = String::new();
    assert_eq!(build_proverb(&input), expected);
}

#[test]
#[ignore]
fn test_full() {
    let input = vec![
        "nail", "shoe", "horse", "rider", "message", "battle", "kingdom",
    ];
    let expected = vec![
        "For want of a nail the shoe was lost.",
        "For want of a shoe the horse was lost.",
        "For want of a horse the rider was lost.",
        "For want of a rider the message was lost.",
        "For want of a message the battle was lost.",
        "For want of a battle the kingdom was lost.",
        "And all for the want of a nail.",
    ]
    .join("\n");
    assert_eq!(build_proverb(&input), expected);
}

#[test]
#[ignore]
fn test_three_pieces_modernized() {
    let input = vec!["pin", "gun", "soldier", "battle"];
    let expected = vec![
        "For want of a pin the gun was lost.",
        "For want of a gun the soldier was lost.",
        "For want of a soldier the battle was lost.",
        "And all for the want of a pin.",
    ]
    .join("\n");
    assert_eq!(build_proverb(&input), expected);
}
```

Comment: @JohnKugelman the post suggested tells how to covert slice str (stored on stack) to String type (on heap) but my question is how can i return String rather than vec<String> .

Comment: The linked post shows how to convert a `Vec<String>` to a `String`, exactly as you need to do.

Comment: I am not getting how the linked post is answering my question both have quite diffrent context

Answer (score 0):

`vecList` has to move out of the else block so it does not return from that scope but from that of the function. Also you might change it to `vecList.join("\n")` so it conforms to the return type String of your function.

[Running on Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=df2e1de777c5d488c511495a51407bdc)